# Can raw SQL be parsed into a Zend\Db\Sql\Select object?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

is there a way to parse a SQL statement string into a `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` object?

something along the lines of:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 = "x"';
$select = new Select();
$select->parseSql($sql);
```

I have many uses for this, basically maintaining the use of a `Select` object when executing a raw SQL statement, for example to pass to `Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect` without having to write a custom `Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect` Class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got one answer through a twitter response, specific to the `Paginator` use case:

```
$resultSet = iterator_to_array($adapter->query($sql_statement)->execute());
$iteratorAdapter = new ArrayAdapter($resultSet);
$paginator = new Paginator($iteratorAdapter);
```

Comment: no benefit if you are searching from huge data.
On every page it'll send all data, although you'll only see some of data on the page. 
On every page, you'll execute something like "select * from table_name"

Comment: it'll not add limit to your query, whereas when using DbSelect Adapter, Paginator will automatically add limit to your query